# Interromper loop na página

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou com um problema, que pesquisei e pensei como fazer, mas não consegui resolver. Tenho um `select` na página que precisa ser populado **após uma condição ser satisfeita**. E após isso, ele precisa consultar os dados relativos a opção escolhida no select. Suponha que esse select seja para preencher o nome de usuários, e após ele ser preenchido, deve ser feita uma consulta no banco com os dados relativos aquele usuário. E é aí que ficou o meu problema, embora consiga preencher o select e trazer os dados relativos ao usuário escolhido, **toda vez que a página é iniciada, o script roda novamente e toda hora fica consultando**. Fica meio que um loop de consultas que não consigo interromper. Como posso fazer com que seja feita apenas uma consulta e após isso, **ele interrompa de modo que a consulta não seja feita novamente**?

> É mais um problema de lógica do que de sintaxe, razão pela qual reduzi
>   o código em si.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (condicao) {
        $.ajax({
            // execução do ajax, aqui preencho o select
        });
        // aqui está o problema, ao preencher o select, é para submeter o form. Porém isso tem causado loop na consulta
    }
    })
    </script>

    <form method="post">
    <select class='form-control' id='opcoes'>
    </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: O que retorna no ajax?

Comment: aquele ajax, retorna dados no formato json, com os quais preencho o select. Após isso, preciso submeter o form, e é esse o meu problema, não sei onde posso colocar esse form para consultar sem que ele fique dando loop com isso

Comment: tudo acontece do jeito que quero, exceto esse loop

Comment: A principio dá pra resolver criando uma flag (true/false) na sessão, onde quando é realizado a operação do ajax, no controller você altera a flag para false. No JS, você pode recuperar uma variável de sessão usando "${flag}".

Comment: bem pensado, uma variável de sessão no próprio javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Bom, vamos lá. Pelo que entendi. Após preencher o select, você gostaria de enviar o form, mas ele continua num loop o Ajax, certo?!

O que você pode fazer pra resolver isso é criar uma variável de "trava" e preenchê-la no success do ajax. Vou tentar dar um exemplo:

```
    var stop = false;
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
if (condicao) {
    if(!stop){
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "some.php",
          data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
        }).done(function() {
            stop = true;
          });
    }
    }
})
</script>

<form method="post">
<select class='form-control' id='opcoes'>
</select>
</form>
```

Aqui tem uns exemplos de utilização de funções no final do ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples

Espero que tenha ajudado. Abraços